# How to check the opengl version in android using adb?

Tags: android, opengl-es, adb

Is it possible to check the version of opengl supported by an android device connected to a pc via ADB? I would also like to know the opengl extensions supported by the devices GPU

Comment: `adb shell dumpsys SurfaceFlinger` or similar service

Comment: Thanks,that worked

Comment: Upper comments give the answer but the output is so big, you can make it short as:
**for windows** run this command in PowerShell: `adb shell dumpsys SurfaceFlinger | Select-String -Pattern "OpenGL"` for Linux run this command: `adb shell dumpsys SurfaceFlinger | grep "OpenGL"`

Comment: It is working, add it as an answer.